# DllMain() doesn't export when I compile in release mode

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I have a DLL that I've developed in VS2015 to implement an external model for a simulation. The DLL exports an obj factory function and DllMain(). When I compile the DLL in debug mode everything works as expected, when I compile in release mode it crashes because DllMain() isn't there.

I've compared the compiler settings and nothing jumps out as being a likely candidate short of disabling the optimization which doesn't seem like a good way to go. I've tried putting a call within the DLL to DllMain() so that the linker would think that it has a reason to include it but it doesn't seem to make difference.

The export declaration looks like this:

```
#ifdef MSVS_CPP
    extern "C" MSVSDLL_API Battery* External_BatteryFactory();
    extern "C" MSVSDLL_API bool DllMain();
#else
    extern "C" Battery* External_BatteryFactory();
    extern "C" bool DllMain();
#endif
```

When I run dumpbin.exe on the resulting DLL, I get this for the debug version:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
(bunch of name mangled member functions)
     39   26 000121A0 DllMain = DllMain
     40   27 000125B0 External_BatteryFactory = External_BatteryFactory
```

and in release mode, I only get this:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
(bunch of name mangled member functions)
     39   26 00002A50 External_BatteryFactory = External_BatteryFactory
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Where does "MSVS_CPP" get defined?  Are you using a linker `.def` file?  (The lack of mangling on these two names makes me think a `.def` is causing export, not `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Furthermore, `DllMain` doesn't need to be exported.  The OS reads the entry point address from the PE header.   Related: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2089/26147

Comment: MSVS_CPP is defined in the preprocessor directives. Not using a .def file, MSVSDLL_API is defined as __declspec(dllexport). Sorry, should have included that in the original post.

Comment: Yes all macros are defined in the preprocessor, but is your `MSVS_CPP` macro defined in your source file, or with a compiler command-line option (which comes from the project file and can be different between Debug and Release builds)?

Comment: Also, that's not the right signature for a `DllMain` function.  You need the parameter to distinguish attach and detach.

Comment: The MSVS_CPP macro is defined with a command-line option in the project file and it's the same between Debug and Release. Didn't realize about the DllMain signature, it seems to work as expected (at least in the debug version) of course maybe that's why it's not getting seen/called in the release.

Comment: Okay, so adjusting the signature of the DllMain makes the code work in release & debug mode. Though the original question still stands, why does that function export as specified in debug mode but not in release mode? Would using a .def file make a difference?

Comment: Read the explanation I linked.  The export is not used for finding DllMain.  The signature is not used for finding DllMain.  Your buggy DllMain simply is causing more trouble in release mode than in debug, which really isn't surprising.